# Preparing an array for vis.js (PHP to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, chap-links-library, vis.js

Trying to transfer data from a GraphDB (Neo4J) via PHP to JavaScript, so vis.js can be used to display those data.

I got so far:

- Reading data from Neo4J and storem them in a PHP array:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 550c2646c4985
            [1] => LOCAL_USER
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 550c267840b7a
            [1] => CSM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 550c4e6e563b9
            [1] => TM
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 550c4e76b0701
            [1] => SM
        )

)
```

- Browsing the net and found json_encode as the right function to transfer the data from PHP to JavaScript:

  `var groups= <?php echo json_encode( $group_nodes ) ?>;`
- vis.js expects the data in an array like

```js
  var nodes = [{
              id: 1,
              label: 'Node 1',
          }, {
              id: 2,
              label: 'Node 2'
          }, {
              id: 3,
              label: 'Node 3'
          }, {
              id: 4,
              label: 'Node 4'
          }, {
              id: 5,
              label: 'Node 5'
          }];
```

I stuck cause I couldnt find a way to get my array into  readable format for vis.js. When I check the javascript array I got all elements, but only comma-separated. It seems vis.js expects them also in the syntax [{...,...},{...,...}].

Any idea how to generate such a format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();

for ($arrData as $value) {
   $newArray[] = array('id' => $value[0], 'label' => $value[1]);
}

$js = json_encode($newArray)
```

Comment: assuming $arrData is the php array you supplied.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks. That helped a lot. Assuming you meant FOREACH-Loop? Cheers, a happy Balael